# Multiple thumbnails in WordPress based on page template?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Is there a way to add multiple thumbnails in a page based on page template or page ID
instead of post type (post, page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a conditional statement to test for a specific page id:

```
if(is_page('<your page id>')){
    // Do your thing
}
```

Similarly, you can test for a specific page template like so:

```
if(is_page_template('<page template file name>']){
   // Go on wit' you bad self
}
```

Make sure that when you use `is_page_template()` that you feed it the file name of the template, e.g., `is_page_template('two-columns.php')`, as opposed to the name of the template, e.g., `is_page_template('Two Columns')`.